# SwiftUI: Button is clickable outside its frame

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-button

I am making log in button for log in page. I have this problem: outside (below, right or left) of the button area, button still gets clicked.
How I fix this?
I want this button to get clicked when I click inside its frame.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginScreenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button {
               //TODO
            } label: {
                LoginButton(textLabel: "Log in")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct LoginScreenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginScreenView()
    }
}

struct LoginButton: View {
    let textLabel: String
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Text(textLabel)
                .font(.navTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                .padding(.horizontal, 100)
                .background(Color(.blue))
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
}
```

[when I click close to this button it gets tapped, even though I am not clicking on the button itself(blue area)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sL8B.png)

Comment: It’s not clear exactly what result you are looking for.

Comment: what is your question here. Why do you have a Button without a view. Why do you have a `v` in `LoginButton(textLabel: "Log In")v`. The code you show does not make sense. Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question, I think its more detailed now. Please see attached image and maybe you can help me out.

Comment: Looks like this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685794

Comment: Yes I also saw that, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct LoginScreenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button {
                // TODO
            } label: {
                LoginButton(textLabel: "Log in")
                    .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Define the clickable area of the button
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried adding contentShape(Rectangle()) , but result is the same, button is clickable outside of its frame.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Hing Tat Tsang! Many of your answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that posting AI-generated content is not allowed here. If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting your own quality content. Thanks!